# Eclipse Oxygen 3a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: centos, java, eclipse

I work in a government building, so I don't have access to install new software of any kind. I have to work with what I have. As of right now I am on a custom version of Centos 7 that I have no control over, and a copy of Eclipse Oxygen 3a April 2018 and I cannot seem to get it to work on Java 10.0.2.

Here is the log file exceptions:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=11.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -?
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -?

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core 4 0 2019-04-19 16:32:56.260
!MESSAGE <null>
!STACK 0
Unexpected token RIGHT SQUARE(]) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:257)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.loadUnknownImages(ImageReplacementService.java:91)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.<init>(ImageReplacementService.java:74)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.<clinit>(ImageReplacementService.java:38)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.internal.images.URLImageDescriptorWeaver.weave(URLImageDescriptorWeaver.java:43)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.AbstractWeaverExtension.weave(AbstractWeaverExtension.java:51)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager$WeavingExtension.weave(InstrumentationManager.java:424)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationManager.weave(InstrumentationManager.java:327)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.patches.internal.InstrumentationWeaver.weave(InstrumentationWeaver.java:15)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.call(WovenClassImpl.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHookPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1298)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.notifyHooksPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:1278)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WovenClassImpl.callHooks(WovenClassImpl.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.weaving.WeavingHookConfigurator.processClass(WeavingHookConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.processClass(ClasspathManager.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.BrandingProperties.getImages(BrandingProperties.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ProductProperties.getWindowImages(ProductProperties.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ProductInfo.getWindowImages(ProductInfo.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getWindowImages(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeImages(Workbench.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-04-19 16:33:03.331
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-04-19 16:33:03.338
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 21 more
```

Here is the eclipse.ini I am using in the .eclipse directory in my home directory:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/java/jdk-10.0.2/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Here is the command I am using to execute eclipse:

```
/opt/eclipse-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse --launcher.ini $ECLIPSE_HOME
```

Here is my environment's ECLIPSE_HOME:

```
/home/me/.eclipse/
```

Before they moved me to Centos 7 to save on Redhat liscenses I was able to get eclipse to work by sourcing rh/devtoolset-4/enable but this is no longer available to me.

As far as I can see from other examples, Eclipse Oxygen 3a is Java 10 capable. I do have --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM in my -vmargs in the eclipse.ini as is suggested in other question's answers. I cannot for the life of me figure out why Eclipse fails to load with this log upon selecting a workspace.

Just to make things clear, I cannot install a new version of eclipse, or reinstall this version. The files don't belong to me. I cannot install another version of Java. I have Java 8, 10, and 11 available, as well as openJDK 7. Nothing else is available to work with.

JAVA_HOME is set to Java 11, but this does not affect Eclipse, as it doesn't use JAVA_HOME, but our product does, and it needs Java 11.

What is it I am missing from the eclipse.ini to get it working?

Comment: The message says that a json file is wrong. Maybe this is true, you are loading a workspace that is corrupt, or not vaild in Oxygen. Try to start Eclipse in a clean environment. Remind that you cannot copy-and-paste projects from a workspace to another.

Comment: The top message says that because it failed in parsing the json before that point due to the class def not found errors. The json it was trying to load I checked, and it did not start with a ']'. I appreciate the comment, but I already found the issue, and it was java not in the build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was in the path variable. For some reason Eclipse Oxygen 3a needs to have Java 1.8 in it's path, even though it uses Java 1.10.

With the transition to Centos, apparently the path to Java 1.8 was changed, and I hadn't updated that.